# How do I make a method in CakePHP output normal HTML after defaulting the controller to JSON?

Tags: html, json, cakephp, view, output

I'm building an Android application and I'm using CakePHP on my server-side. I have a UsersController where it returns JSON data for login, register, etc, apart from accountActivation. Since this account activation method is only called in a web browser client I want to display a simple HTML page and not output JSON. How can I do this after I have defaulted my controller to return JSON data? I've defaulted it to JSON with  `public $viewClass = 'Json';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this chapter, this describes it how to do json views the best way.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

If I understand your question right you want to send HTML after the json has been sent? Well, you can't return two different things in the same response.

If you're looking for separating the data read the link. Just add the json extension like /users/action.json and you'll get a json response, if not HTML .